# "Raspberry Pi 3 B" rebooted infinitely on Android Things

Tags: wifi, android, android-things, reboot

More than 30 Wi-Fi APs are scanned in our office.

if... I turn on the WiFi module on "Android Things",

"Raspberry Pi 3 B" will be rebooted infinitely.

Turning off multiple WiFi APs, sometimes does not reboot.

I want to know the reason. It's a serious problem for us.

Comment: any useful information / errors displayed / error log entries (when you get a stable pi of course)

Comment: Is there a specific app it's running?

Comment: No.

I did not install the Apps.

I have installed Android Things for the first time.

When I turn on the WiFi, it reboots.

Raspberry Pi 3 turns off immediately when scanning a WiFi list.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: Does it work on ethernet? Can you try a different power source?

Comment: Thank you for reply. Ethernet works well. and I've also used a different power source.(Raspberry Pi power, 5V 2A power, etc.)  
Changing the power didn't solve the problem.
I have five Raspberry Pi,All the same problems appear.
Only when WIFI is turned on will loop reboot.

Comment: Do you have the same problem with a single AP?

Comment: There is no problem with a single AP.